# Mod rewrite for query string

Tags: mod-rewrite

Mod Rewrite noob so pardon my ignorance but all I am trying to do is a simple query string removal

from: `http://yourwebsite.com/x?section=y`

to: `http://yourwebsite.com/x/y`

I am adding my mod rewrite rules in my **.htaccess** like this:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404

Options +MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^section=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1/%1? [R=301,L,NE]
```

The problem is that on visiting:

```
http://yourwebsite.com/x?section=y
```

My rule writes it back as:

```
http://yourwebsite.com/x.php/y
```

That **.php** in the pretty url is pretty darn ugly and I am struggling to get rid of it.

What is wrong in my mod rewrite rule?

Comment: Most likely a file `x.php` exists, so the first `RewriteRule` matches and rewrites the request to `x.php`. Just as you configured it to do. So what is it you want to do instead?

Comment: `x.php` exists. It can be visited by `http://yourwebsite.com/x`. I want urls like `http://yourwebsite.com/x?section=y` to rewrite to `http://yourwebsite.com/x/y`. Currently, they are rewritten as `http://yourwebsite.com/x.php/y`

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you are looking for something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)\/(.+)$ /$1.php?section=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^section=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1/%1 [R=301,L,NE]
```

It makes two rewrites:

1. a request `x/y` is internally rewritten to `x.php?section=y`
2. a request to `x?section=y` is redirected to `x/y`

Note that one is an internal rewrite, whilst the other redirects the browser to show a less 'ugly' url.

One hint: in case you can use the logging feature of apaches rewriting module (`RewriteLog` and `RewriteLogLevel`) this will offer you a wealth of detailed information on what is actually going on inside the rewrite process.

Comment: I dont want the `point 1`. I just want the `point 2`. My rules almost works except that I am unable to get rid of the ugly .php. After rule application `x?section=y` looks like `x.php/y`

Comment: Well a) look at my comment to your question: you explicitly configure the rewrite to x.php with your own first `RewriteRule` and b) I'd say that you can change that, but then x.php will not get called, you will get an error that `/x` does not exist.

Comment: Question: when `x/y` is requested, do you want `x.php` be executed (probably with the argument `section=y`) or what else should be requested internally as `x`?